# How can I use an event to select a query selector to select an entity to copy the rotation of another entity?

Tags: aframe

In this component code I am trying to use an event to select the meaning of the variable called "name"
to select which entity will copy another entities rotation as the user watches.

Different events will result in different rotations.

So event 1 means that name equals querySelector Object A

Then I am trying to have row get it's own rotation and give it to name's (to) animation and then start
name's animation by emitting moveobject to name.

However I am currently stuck on this problem after investing many hours trying to solve it. Help?

```
    AFRAME.registerComponent("comp", {
       init: function () {
           let name = {}
           this.el.addEventListener("event1", (e) => {
             name = document.querySelector('#objectA');
             console.log('event1')
// line 13?   comp.emit('rowstart)
           });
           this.el.addEventListener("event2", (e) => {
             name = document.querySelector('#objectB');
             console.log('event2')
           });

           let row = document.querySelector('#rowA');
           row.addEventListener('rowstart', function (e) {
               var rotation = row.getAttribute('rotation')
               name.setAttribute('animation', {
                   to: {
                       x: rotation.x,
                       y: rotation.y,
                       z: rotation.z - 30
                   }
               })
           name.emit('moveobject')
           });
       }
   });
```

I should mention that this link below is what my code looks like when it is ONLY copying rotation, and not using an event to select which entity will be rotated https://glitch.com/edit/#!/copy-rotation?path=index.html:37:8 (edited)

Answer (score 0):

`to` is not a vector property, you have to pass it as a string.

```
name.setAttribute('animation', 'to', `${rotation.x} ${rotation.y} ${rotation.z}`);
```

Comment: okay I turned to into a string 'to', but that already worked in my sample code on glitch.com linked above both before and after I turned it into a string. I suspect that the part that I need to fix is how to start the event called "rowstart" once the name querySelector is selected by an event outside this script, on line 13 I am wondering if I need an emit statement there or something else

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do exactly, maybe helps if you narrow/t;dr down the question to a single technical question without the whole context of the project. Maybe you are asking about event details? You can pass an event detail. `someEl.emit('eventName',  value)` and then `value` will be passed to the event handler `evt.detail`. You can also pass elements or objects this way too.

Comment: I did manage to complete this code a couple days ago and here is video of what it looks like when its supposed to work as its intended to work https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=2631449130215051&id=100000499704585&_rdr

However the way we went about solving it was completely different to your proposed solution which is fine except that now I want to learn how to re-solve what has already been solved your way just to improve my understanding of how A-Frame works. I struggle with describing what I am trying to do in a narrowed down way, but I will try again to do that.